# How to remove home page title in Yoast SEO?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I'm using a static Page as the WP site home/front page. The page title always uses the site title no matter what page title was entered, which works as expected.

But as soon as Yoast SEO gets activated, It outputs both the page title and site title, e.g.

Let's say the site title is "My Site Title".

- If I set the page title to "My Page Title", it outputs "My Page Title - My Site Title"
- If I set the page title to "Homepage", it outputs "Homepage - My Site Title"

How do I remove the extra title, and only use the site title for the homepage, same as the default WP behavior only "My Site Title"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, you have two possibilities. You can setup this configuration for all the pages or each page individually.

For all the pages simply go to SEO > Search Appearance then select *Content Types*. There, you will find the default configuration for each content type and the one of pages will look like this:

[image]

You simply need to remove *separator* and *site title*.

---

If you want to change this for each page individually you need to edit the page. Locate the Yoast block, click on the title then edit it:

[image]